# NSTableCellView not displaying data in MonoMac

Tags: c#, nstableview, monomac

I'm facing a problem on how display custom data in my NSTableCellView using MonoMac.

Here is a screenshot of my Ui Designer :

[image: NSTableCellView in UI Designer]

And here is the code I use in my NSTableViewDataSource :

```
public class ClientsTableController : NSTableViewDataSource
{
    NSTableView _tv;

    public ClientsTableController (NSTableView tableView)
    {
        _tv = tableView;
        _tv.DataSource = this;
        SharedGlobals.ClientListIsModified += ClientListIsModified;
    }

    private void ClientListIsModified()
    {
        _tv.ReloadData ();
    }

    public override int GetRowCount (NSTableView tableView)
    {
        return SharedGlobals.Clients.Count;
    }

    public override NSObject GetObjectValue (NSTableView tableView, NSTableColumn tableColumn, int row)
    {
        Client currentClient = SharedGlobals.Clients.Values.ToList () [row];
        NSTableCellView tcv = (NSTableCellView)(tableView.MakeView ("ClientCellView", _tv));
        NSTextField username_tf = (NSTextField)(tcv.Subviews [0]);
        username_tf.StringValue = currentClient.Username;
        return tcv;
    }
}
```

This is not working properly, the view returned seems to be not correctly loaded : As you can see here the variables are good in code but are not displayed correctly.

[image: Result in inspector]
[image: Result]

I already checked if `NSTextField username_tf = (NSTextField)(tcv.Subviews [0]);` was returning the good UI item, and it is.

Did I miss something ?